# Why the infinite loop?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I am trying to find if the number is a perfect square, but for some reason my code goes into an infinite loop and keeps printing "yes". Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int N=0, n=0, l=1, u=0, mid;

  cin >> N;

  for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
  {
    cin >> n;
    u=n;

    while (l <= u)  
    {   
      mid = (l+u)/2;

      if (n == mid*mid) 
      {   
        cout << "yes" << endl;
        continue;
      }   
      else if (n > mid*mid)
      {   
        l = mid+1;
      }
      else if (n < mid*mid)
      {
        u = mid-1;
      }
    }
    cout << "no" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And the input file is:

```
15
1
2
4
9
16
25
35
753
23446
23423
5423
81
49
36
100
121
```

The first entry is the number of values that we want to check which is 15 in this case.
I looked this code over and over again and still cannot spot why I'm getting the infinite loop.

Comment: Maybe it's time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Seconding what nvoigt said. But for starters, you probably want `break` instead of `continue` ... (but that won't be enough on its own, you'll need some extra logic to *not* print `no` in that case).

Comment: @nvoigt I tried using gdb and it just goes into the same infinite loop so I cannot get any info that way.

Comment: @DCoder Yeah it seems like when I put in break, the logic breaks as well and I start to get wrong answers due to that "no".

Comment: @DCoder I put in a boolean b to get rid of the "no" and it fixed some output but the last 5 entries are still printing as a "no" when they should print "yes" any idea why?

Comment: @Urler: once you print out `"yes"`, you should probably break out of the `for` loop as well. (And rename `b` to `found` for readability's sake.)

Comment: @DCoder if I break out of the for loop after I print "yes" I won't be able to check the rest of the input.  Since I want to check all 15 values I need to iterate through them all and print yes or no for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. inside the for loop ,you should reset

> l=1

2. change `continue` to `break`

Answer (score 0):

your approach needs to be worked on a little bit.. you should implement something simpler if you can't get yours working.

some psuedo code to work with:

```
/* also note that you should add in conditions to make sure number 
   is positive, and greater than 2, and if it is two, to return 1   */

function check_if_perfect_square(int number) {
    int i = 2
    while (i*i <= number) {
        if (i*i == number) {
            print("perfect square");
            return 1;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    print("not a perfect square");
    return 0;
}
```

read in the numbers 1 at a time and check them with a function... the key to identifying issues likes yours is modularization...  have 1 function reading in the data, and 1 function checking if it is a perfect square or not

Comment: your approach is O(2^n) exponential time I want something faster so the way I am doing it is O(log(n)) assuming all numbers don't go over of 32-bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (n == mid*mid) 
  {   
    cout << "yes" << endl;
    continue;
  }
```

'continue' just continues execution from the top of the while loop again. Once (n == mid*mid) is true, it will stay true, causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You reinitialize `u` (with `u=n;`) at the top of every iteration of the outer loop, but you don't reinitialize `l`, so it ends up at whatever value it was set to during a previous iteration of the loop.

Try looking at the values of `l` at the end of the iterations where `n` gets the values 
23446, 23423, and 5423.  If it ends up being set to 122 or any larger value, then for
the last five iterations `while (l <= u)` will not loop at all (because `l` is already
greater than `u`) and you will go straight to printing out "no".

You could try setting `l = 0;` immediately before or after you set `u = n;` 
and see if that helps.